# mysql select query with empty value

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing one issue while issuing below query. I am not sure what am i doing wrong?

```
$start= date("y-m-d", strtotime($start));        
$end= date("y-m-d", strtotime($end));
//    $start = '2016-03-03';
//   $end= '2016-04-04';
if($jobtitle == ''){
    $jobtitle = true;
}
if($start == '' or $end == ''){
    $start = true;
    $end = true;
}
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM postdata 
                            where id = ? 
                              and title = ? 
                              and (date between ? and ?) 
                            order by date desc");

$result ->bind_param("isss", $id, $title, $start, $end);
$result->execute();
```

Actually i have a form with 3 fields. 1 title and others 2 are start and end for date.

If user either enter value in title or put start and end date in the form. User can also put values in both filed. Once data is submitted by user then i want to perform search in database.

Please advise why my query is not working.

Comment: Simple code indentation not only makes the code easier to read it also makes **debugging** much easier

Comment: `= is assignment`  and `== or ===` is an equality test.

Comment: `title = '%%'` says the content of the `title` column must contain `%%` and only `%%`. You are not using a LIKE and that is the only syntax that responds to `%` characters

Comment: `true` is not going to help you either

Comment: This is what i have at the moment.

Comment: If the fields the user can enter are optional then you will have to build the query dynamically to fit the fields that were actually entered

Comment: all fields are optional but once form submit it will check any one of them have value or not. If not then it will show error to user.

Comment: So you are saying that you are testing these 3 fields somewhere and if ANY fields is not entered you throw an error and DO NOT run this query?

Comment: Correct. I have input validation. If data is found any one of them then it will execute query.

Comment: Then see my previous comment. Build the query dynamically based on the actual fields entered. You cannot pass `true` to a `date between ...` and expect it to work or anything that is not actually a date come to that

Comment: Now i am thinking to write select query for every if condition.

Comment: That is a solution! Not necessarily the best solution but it is a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created three separate select queries in if condition and it resolves the issue.
Here is the code which i am using at the moment.

```
 if($title != '' and $_POST['start'] == '' and $_POST['end'] == ''){
      $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM posting where id = ? and title like ? order by date desc");
      $result ->bind_param("is", $id, $title);
 }
 if($title == '' and $_POST['start'] != '' and $_POST['end'] != ''){
      $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM posting where id = ? and (date between ? and ?) order by date desc");
      $result ->bind_param("iss", $id, $start, $end);
            }
 if($title != '' and $_POST['start'] != '' and $_POST['end'] != ''){
      $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM posting where id = ? and title like ? and (date between ? and ?) order by date desc");
      $result ->bind_param("isss", $id, $title, $start, $end);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply re-bind these variables in your IF statement

```
if($start = '' or $end = '')
```

There must be boolean operators like === or ==

Comment: Although that whole IF is a bit of nonsense if you look at it even with the correct usage of `==`

Comment: Applogies but = was typo. I already tried == but it is not returning any data.

Comment: Agree. The date() function won't return an empty string any way. The check should be before the transformation. However with '=' in IF statement it hasn't any chance :)